# Change the background color of a span element when it is clicked

Tags: html, css

For changing the color during hover I have a css statement like `span:hover{......}`. Is there any direct css option available (not javascript) to specify when the span element is clicked ?

Comment: `span:active` changes the bgcolor only during the click operation. That is during mouse down to mouse up of a click. I was wondering if there is any direct way to specify css based on element state namely 'clicked' or 'unclicked'. Thanks for your response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to use :active?

```
span:active
```

Comment: `span:active` changes the bgcolor only during the click operation. That is during mouse down to mouse up of a click. I was wondering if there is any direct way to specify css based on element state namely 'clicked' or 'unclicked'. Thanks for your response..

Comment: '$('span').css('background-color','red') if you are planning to go with jquery route

Answer (score 0):

`span:active`, however most versions of Internet Explorer will ignore this rule

Answer (score 0):

You will need to capture and process the `click` event, which is javascript.  There is no way to do this with pure HTML/ CSS.

The `:active` CSS psuedoclass does not persist its styling beyond the click.